# How to import and perform calculation in a las files on python?

Tags: python, las, log-ascii-standard

I hope you are all well.

I want to handle `.las` files in python. These are specific `ascii` files for geophysical profiling. They have a header and then a series of columns containing various information.

What is the best way to start?

The main objective would be to add new columns that would be mathematical operations of the other columns. And operations between values ​​in the same column.

Below we have an example of a `.las` file.

```
~Version Information
VERS.              2.00                     : CWLS Log ASCII Standard - Version 2.00
WRAP.              NO                       : One line per depth step
#
~Well Information
#MNEM.UNIT         DATA                     : DESCRIPTION      
#----.----         ---------                : -----------------
STRT .M             25.000                  : Start
STOP .M            251.000                  : Stop
STEP .M              0.010                  : Step increment
NULL .             -999.250                 : Null value
COMP .             VALE DO RIO DOCE         : Company
WELL .             GAL-FD00033              : Well
FLD  .             PICO                     : Field
PROV .             QUADRILATERO FERRIFERO   : Province / County
CTRY .             MINAS GERAIS             : State / Country
LOC  .             BRASIL                   : Location
LOC2 .                                      : Location 2
SRVC .             Weatherford              : Service company
UWI  .                                      : Unique Well ID
LATI .             7763458M                 : Latitude
LONG .             619198M                  : Longitude
DATE .             18-Sep-2014              : Logging date
#
~Curve Information
#MNEM.UNIT         API CODES                : CURVE DESCRIPTION
#----.----         ---------                : -----------------
DEPT .M            00 001 00 00             : Logged depth
CADE .MM           45 280 01 00             : Caliper from DD6
BIT  .MM           70 282 00 00             : Bit size
GRC1 .GAPI         45 310  1 00             : Gamma Ray from GC1-GC2
DD3L .CPS          00 000 00 00             : Long Spaced Density Raw
DD3B .CPS          00 000 00 00             : Short Spaced Density Raw
DENL .G/C3         45 350 02 00             : Density Long Spaced
DENB .G/C3         45 350 02 00             : Density Short Spaced
GRDE .API          45 310 01 00             : Gamma Ray from DD6
CCO1 .MM           42 280  1 00             : 3-Arm Caliper CO1-GC2
CO1C .CPS           0   0  0 00             : Caliper Raw
DD3G .CPS          00 000 00 00             : Gamma Ray Raw
GC1G .CPS           0   0  0 00             : Gamma Ray Raw
DD3C .CPS          00 000 00 00             : Caliper Raw
GTMP .DEGC         80 660  2 00             : Borehole Temperature
GRDO .API          45 310 01 00             : Gamma Ray from Density O
DNBO .G/C3         45 350 02 00             : Density Short Spaced OPE
DNLO .G/C3         45 350 02 00             : Density Long Spaced OPEN
CCLF .CPS           0   0  0 00             : Casing Collar Locator
#
~Parameter Information
#MNEM.UNIT         VALUE                    : DESCRIPTION      
#----.----         ---------                : -----------------
RNID .             MAIN LOG                 : Run ID
EREF .M            1512.610                 : Elevation of depth reference
DREF .             K.B.                     : Depth reference
GL   .M            1511.000                 : Ground elevation
RUN  .             2                        : Run number
TDD  .M            255.000                  : TD (driller)
TDL  .M            226.000                  : TD (logger)
CSGD .M            252.600                  : Casing bottom (driller)
CSGL .M            251.000                  : Casing bottom (logger)
BS   .MM           77.80                    : Bit size
MUD  .             WATER BASED              : Mud type
MUDD .K/M3                                  : Mud density
MUDV .CP                                    : Mud viscosity
PH   .                                      : Mud pH
FL   .ML/30MIN                              : Mud fluid loss rate
MUDS .             N/A                      : Mud sample source
TMAX .DEGC         20.12                    : Max recorder temperature
TIMC .DAY/HR                                : Time circulation ended
TIML .DAY/HR                                : Time logger at bottom
UNIT .             11613                    : Equipment ID
BASE .                                      : Equipment base location
ENG  .             SIONEY/DEIVISON/HELBERT  : Recording engineer
WIT  .             GEOSERVICE               : Witnessed by
CSUP .FEET         -999999.000              : Casing Stick Up GL
CSGS .MM           60.100                   : Casing size
CSGW .KG/M         0.00                     : Casing weight
CSGT .             NQ                       : Casing Type
#
~Other Information
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOOLS LOGGED IN CASED HOLE

HQ - 25.00M TO 147.00
NQ - 147.00 TO 251.00

GC2 TD @  226.00M 

DD6 TD @ 226.00M


ON SITE: 10:00
START: 10:15
FINISH:11:50

WATER LEVEL - 66.50M



LOGGING JOB REQUESTED BY WANDERSON PEREIRA / DIONISIO CARLOS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~A    DEPT       CADE        BIT       GRC1       DD3L       DD3B       DENL       DENB       GRDE       CCO1       CO1C       DD3G       GC1G       DD3C       GTMP       GRDO       DNBO       DNLO       CCLF
    25.000     78.687     77.800     26.421     19.000    439.000      3.351      4.358     51.334     79.631   1461.000     22.000     13.000   2013.000     19.108     61.720      3.602      2.940      0.136
    25.010     78.696     77.800     28.308     26.000    416.000      3.341      4.360     48.032     79.485   1451.000     23.000     13.000   2007.000     19.111     60.250      3.609      2.937     -0.009
    25.020     78.682     77.800     28.151     26.000    420.000      3.337      4.368     40.077     79.654   1465.000     31.000      0.000   2011.000     19.098     58.926      3.618      2.933     -0.055
    25.030     78.687     77.800     28.151     13.000    425.000      3.336      4.381     38.876     79.639   1455.000     30.000     13.000   2011.000     19.096     56.894      3.625      2.932      0.355
    25.040     78.689     77.800     32.240     26.000    403.000      3.333      4.387     37.825     79.747   1467.000     23.000     26.000   2013.000     19.089     54.335      3.634      2.933     -0.136
    25.050     78.684     77.800     34.284     25.000    412.000      3.338      4.401     34.523     79.774   1455.000     24.000     38.000   2006.000     19.104     51.650      3.643      2.936     -0.336
    25.060     78.670     77.800     32.240     25.000    428.000      3.347      4.406     32.422     79.803   1461.000     23.000     38.000   2013.000     19.096     48.656      3.652      2.939      0.291
    25.070     78.675     77.800     32.240     19.000    406.000      3.360      4.414     32.422     79.462   1458.000      0.000     25.000   2009.000     19.094     46.587      3.659      2.943     -0.100
    25.080     78.618     77.800     34.284     13.000    377.000      3.373      4.423     27.769     79.401   1458.000     15.000      0.000   2008.000     19.098     45.753      3.665      2.950      0.145
    25.090     78.642     77.800     34.284     33.000    392.000      3.384      4.430     26.718     79.341   1461.000     23.000     26.000   2009.000     19.109     45.063      3.670      2.958      0.518
    25.100     78.648     77.800     32.240     13.000    388.000      3.405      4.421     26.718     79.285   1461.000     16.000     26.000   2011.000     19.118     44.356      3.676      2.966      0.018
    25.110     78.602     77.800     26.264     19.000    424.000      3.425      4.429     26.568     79.421   1449.000      8.000      0.000   2011.000     19.096     44.446      3.679      2.973      0.482
    25.120     78.603     77.800     24.377     13.000    390.000      3.444      4.435     30.921     79.738   1464.000     23.000     13.000   2009.000     19.098     45.335      3.680      2.983      0.000
    25.130     78.678     77.800     28.466     19.000    396.000      3.460      4.443     33.172     79.551   1455.000      0.000     13.000   2011.000     19.111     46.769      3.681      2.991     -0.018
    25.140     78.647     77.800     32.397     19.000    401.000      3.474      4.433     33.172     79.634   1468.000     23.000     13.000   2011.000     19.101     48.910      3.685      2.998      0.018
    25.150     78.651     77.800     34.284     13.000    431.000      3.491      4.433     31.971     79.573   1452.000     23.000     13.000   2009.000     19.103     51.178      3.689      3.005      0.018
    25.160     78.721     77.800     36.329     19.000    389.000      3.500      4.432     35.274     79.430   1462.000     23.000      0.000   2008.000     19.104     53.301      3.692      3.010     -0.509
    25.170     78.693     77.800     38.373     19.000    409.000      3.507      4.450     39.777     79.266   1468.000     52.000     26.000   2013.000     19.108     55.587      3.696      3.017     -0.082
    25.180     78.660     77.800     36.329     19.000    385.000      3.513      4.454     44.280     79.529   1451.000     15.000     51.000   2009.000     19.103     56.676      3.704      3.022     -0.482
    25.190     78.653     77.800     36.329     13.000    405.000      3.520      4.459     45.480     79.572   1465.000     15.000     25.000   2011.000     19.119     57.637      3.711      3.025     -0.491
    25.200     78.648     77.800     34.284     19.000    392.000      3.525      4.468     45.480     79.688   1452.000     15.000     38.000   2006.000     19.109     58.744      3.719      3.027     -0.400
    25.210     78.619     77.800     32.240     13.000    389.000      3.522      4.486     44.280     79.696   1465.000     38.000     39.000   2011.000     19.088     59.851      3.722      3.031     -0.600
    25.220     78.637     77.800     36.329     20.000    373.000      3.520      4.481     45.480     79.658   1459.000     38.000     13.000   2013.000     19.111     60.414      3.724      3.033     -0.345
    25.230     78.646     77.800     36.329     13.000    379.000      3.521      4.484     39.927     79.580   1462.000     53.000      0.000   2009.000     19.101     60.160      3.723      3.034     -0.073
    25.240     78.688     77.800     32.397     19.000    383.000      3.518      4.470     41.127     79.621   1456.000      8.000     13.000   2006.000     19.094     58.672      3.720      3.034      0.400
    25.250     78.669     77.800     34.599     19.000    375.000      3.518      4.467     42.328     79.658   1458.000     23.000      0.000   2013.000     19.114     57.166      3.713      3.035      0.445
    25.260     78.680     77.800     36.801     19.000    380.000      3.514      4.454     41.127     79.562   1458.000     15.000      0.000   2007.000     19.108     55.932      3.705      3.035      1.091
    25.270     78.694     77.800     32.712     13.000    403.000      3.517      4.450     39.927     79.573   1462.000     31.000     26.000   2009.000     19.094     54.716      3.693      3.034      0.118
    25.280     78.662     77.800     32.712     19.000    400.000      3.516      4.439     37.675     79.408   1456.000     15.000     26.000   2017.000     19.098     53.065      3.681      3.034      0.464
    25.290     78.619     77.800     34.756     13.000    427.000      3.512      4.425     31.971     79.314   1459.000     23.000     26.000   2009.000     19.118     52.357      3.667      3.035      0.209
    25.300     78.637     77.800     36.801     19.000    414.000      3.509      4.409     33.022     79.256   1459.000     23.000     39.000   2009.000     19.106     51.922      3.655      3.035     -0.109
    25.310     78.645     77.800     38.845     19.000    428.000      3.509      4.389     35.274     79.499   1461.000      7.000     52.000   2009.000     19.088     51.613      3.642      3.035     -0.745
    25.320     78.636     77.800     42.934     13.000    401.000      3.510      4.374     34.223     79.515   1452.000     30.000     13.000   2013.000     19.114
```

Comment: Maybe [laspy](https://pypi.org/project/laspy/) or [liblas](https://liblas.org/tutorial/python.html) or [lasio](https://lasio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is what you need?

Comment: Have a look at the lasio library https://lasio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try Kinverity's Lasio tool at https://github.com/kinverarity1/lasio. The current version as of June 2022 is [v0.30](https://github.com/kinverarity1/lasio/releases/tag/v0.30).  It is stable and in practical use.

Lasio has the capability to write a new las file from modified data. I am pretty sure you can add new columns as described in the question.

Use Python3 if possible because Python2 support ended August 2020.

See the full documentation at:
https://lasio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Install instructions:

For the minimum working requirements, you'll need numpy installed. Install lasio with:

```
$ pip install lasio
```

To make sure you have everything, use this to ensure pandas, cchardet, and openpyxl are also installed:

```
$ pip install lasio[all]
```

Example session:

```
>>> import lasio
You can read the file using a filename, file-like object, or URL:

>>> las = lasio.read("sample_rev.las")

>>> las.keys()
['DEPT', 'DT', 'RHOB', 'NPHI', 'SFLU', 'SFLA', 'ILM', 'ILD']
>>> las['SFLU']
array([ 123.45,  123.45,  123.45, ...,  123.45,  123.45,  123.45])
>>> las['DEPT']
array([ 1670.   ,  1669.875,  1669.75 , ...,  1669.75 ,  1670.   ,
        1669.875])
```

From there you can perform a various operations on the Log Ascii Standard data via the `las` object.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to import your las file using lasio and then utilize pandas and numpy to handle your data and do your calculations

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import lasio

#read the file
las = lasio.read("file.las")
```

once your file is read , you can utilize pandas by converting the las to pandas data framework

```
df=las.df()
```

to add a column or a calaulated cuve you can use the guide code below :
let's say you want to create curve (NEW) which is equal to DD3L + DD3B of your dataset.

```
df_copy=df.copy()        # Just create a copy of your data
df_copy['NEW'] = (df_copy.DD3L()) + (df_copy.DD3B())
```